# Change the RT shader used for the 3d view?

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

The model I'm working on uses a weird [Cg-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cg_(programming_language)) shader. Is there a way I can run it in the 3d-view so that I can see what I'm doing?

Comment: Blender supports [GLSL](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/), because it is the most portable way to do it. You could port Cg to GLSL - maybe even with the help of nvidias [cgc compiler](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/cgc.html)  and use that in blenders game engine. Though this assumes a certain understanding of Cg, GLSL and some limitations inside BGE.